# Ljava/lang/String error with jstring / c++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am running elementary OS 64-bit. Eclipse ADT.

Hello I am trying to get a string from C++ to java via JNI.

I am however receiving two problems depending on how I try and run my application.

- error) following error when I `run in eclipse`

[image]

[image]

- Here is the file structure in eclipse

[image]

- Here is the the java build path including the native library in eclipse

[image]

Here are the files.

**Controller.java**

```
package sslarp.controller;

public class Controller {

    private native String getMyMac();       // returns the current machines mac address
    private native String getMyIp();        // returns the current machines ip address

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("getmacip");
    }

    private String myMac;
    private String myIp;

    public Controller() {

    }

    public void run() { 
        myMac = getMyMac();
        myIp = getMyIp();

        System.out.println("java: mac "+myMac+"\njava: ip "+myIp+"\n");     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println("java: starting");

        Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.run();
    }
}
```

**Controller.class** was made via the **javac** command resides in `/home/karl/workspace/sslarp/bin/sslarp/controller/Controller.class`

**sslarp_controller_Controller.h** which is generated via the `javah` command

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class sslarp_controller_Controller */

#ifndef _Included_sslarp_controller_Controller
#define _Included_sslarp_controller_Controller
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     sslarp_controller_Controller
 * Method:    getMyMac
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_sslarp_controller_Controller_getMyMac
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

/*
 * Class:     sslarp_controller_Controller
 * Method:    getMyIp
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_sslarp_controller_Controller_getMyIp
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**getmacip.cpp** I made this by myself

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_sslarp_controller_Controller_getMyMac
  (JNIEnv *jenv, jobject jobj)
{
    printf("c: getMyMac() invoked!\n");

    char str[] = "foo";    

    jstring jstr = jenv->NewStringUTF(str);
    return jstr;
}


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_sslarp_controller_Controller_getMyIp
  (JNIEnv *jenv, jobject jobj)
{
    printf("c: getMyMac() invoked!\n");

    char str[] = "bar";    

    jstring jstr = jenv->NewStringUTF(str);
    return jstr;
}
```

**libgetmacip.so** made via the command `karl@karl-vm:~/workspace/sslarp/bin$ g++ -fPIC -o libgetmacip.so -shared -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/linux getmacip.cpp -lc`

I also an the following command `karl@karl-vm:~/workspace/sslarp/bin$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/karl/workspace/sslarp/lib/` to add the library to the java path

Comment: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` has to do with the native library not being found.  It has nothing to do with returning a string to Java from C++.

Comment: I'd recommend to try google and/or java documentation before asking SO

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Alright! Any ideas to what I may have done wrong? I have my .class java file in bin/package/file.class and the .so, .cpp and .h are in same directory!

Comment: Probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903530/how-should-i-load-native-libraries-for-jni-to-avoid-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror" contains an answer

Comment: @KarlMorrison - Oh, and BTW, the code you posted will work once you get your native library issues straightened out.

Comment: Please also post your Java code. Let's see how you define the native method in your Java class.

Comment: @yushulx updated the entire question with a lot more information!

Comment: @KarlMorrison - You say you're using 64-bit Eclipse.  Are you running a 64-bit JVM?  If so, then the native library has to be 64-bit.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I got it working with C however, via the same procedure (nearly)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I figured it out, forgot to include the header file in the .cpp file... DOH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include the code `#include "sslarp_controller_Controller.h"` in the `getmacip.cpp` file.

Basically I forgot to add the header to the .cpp file.