# Load native libraries using JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

How to load native libraries using JNI?

I tried to load but i am getting error as

```
Native code library failed to load. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
```

Comment: Provide your code please.

Comment: That should help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903530/how-should-i-load-native-libraries-for-jni-to-avoid-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror it will help you